# Should I run wp cron event run via crontab or as a daemon?

Tags: wp-cli, cron

In my server I've run:

```sh
 sudo -u www-data wp cron event run --path=/var/www/blog.example.com --all
```

But I do not know should I run wordpress cron using crontab or make it into a service using systemd or my server's init system?

Upon that I have looped upon https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/cron/event/run/ and I see no referent about that.

Comment: I doubt it makes any difference. Except maybe if you have extremely long running cron jobs, so that cron might be running when the next batch would start, but that shouldn't happen.

Comment: that's already a concern no matter how you execute cron, this decision has zero impact on that

Comment: Note that the OP asked how to run WP CLI but is not interested in that question and is actually asking if WP CLI is a daemon/service, the question should have stated this, since it's possible to trigger the cron event using systemd even if it was not a daemon

Answer (score 1):

As far as WP and WP CLI is concerned it will make **zero** difference, and that is why it does not tell you to use one or the other.

Both will work, there are no WordPress based advantages or disadvantages that make one more correct than the other.

All the things that matter in this decision are on you, and your personal preference.

### Which One Is More *Correct*?

*Neither*, WordPress has never made a recommendation, and both are just as valid as each other. It's entirely down to personal preference.

I will say though, that crontab is more popular because it is easier to set up.

### Is WP CLI A Service?

This wasn't asked in your question but I suspect this is what you mean based on this comment:

> does the wp-cli runs as daemon or not

No, WP CLI commands run then finish, they are not long running tasks.

If you run this:

```sh
wp cron event run --all
```

It will execute cron and run all tasks, *then exit*. If new cron tasks are added or cron tasks reoccur then you would need to re-run the cron command.

All WP CLI commands are just commands, they are not long-running background tasks or daemons/services.

Comment: The question is does the `wp-cli` runs as daemon or not.

Comment: **That's not what you wrote in your question,** even if it's what you intended, you should edit your question. I can only write an answer for the question you asked. You should have directly asked if WP CLI is a long running task/daemon in your question instead of asking how to run WP CLI. I can see why it might seem obvious to you, but there are ways to run non-daemon commands on regular basis using systemd/services on Linux. I've made some changes to my answer but you need to edit your original question so it isn't confusing for other people